# How to change network to private on Windows IoT?

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

How do I change network to private in Windows IoT via IoT Dashboard's Device Portal? I know it's set to public because an app I develop has only private networking on and it's not connecting.

Comment: Have you tried to use a search engine to find the answer first?

Comment: @MatsK yes, and I was suprised I coudn't find an answer!

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/iotdashboard

Comment: Well, there is no answer to my question on the site, I was there... it's only how to connect to the device connected to a network that is private or public from the point of view of the Windows 10 PC, not Windows 10 IoT device's.